# Error 500 with large arrays

Tags: php, json

I'm attempting to read an XML file on a separate domain. This XML file has around 250 `<entries>` and only one of the `children` is using a `namespace`. This `child` is a string of geo coordinates (latitude and longitude longitude separated by a space). In some of these `entries` there can be roughly 15,000 separate items.

My issue is when I attempt to pass this information from my server to the client using JSON the server spits out an `error 500`. What's interesting is that the script works fine on my localhost running XAMPP.

I cannot use AJAX to retrieve and parse the information due to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. I would prefer to use AJAX if possible, but I couldn't figure it out.

SCRIPT:

```
if ($xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.dot.nd.gov/travel-info-v2/georss/loadrestrict-current.xml")) {
    $ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
    $return = array();

    foreach ($xml->entry as $value) {

        $value->geo = $value->children($ns["georss"]);
        $return[] = $value;
    }

    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

Comment: What does you log file say ?

Comment: look at the server error log for details about the 500. most likely you're exceeding php's memory limit, which kills everything.

Comment: add the following at the top of your php script `ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/php_errors.log');`make sure php has write permissions on the current dir.

Comment: Right, the 500 error log is saying that the memory limit has been reached. I've modified the code to add the error log and added an php_errors.log file with permissions 744, but nothing was added to it.

Comment: Can you curl the file to your server and load it locally? Seems lioke your loop might be exhausting all the memory as it iterates over all the XML items.

Comment: I've tried changing my code up a bit to avoid creating an array. http://pastebin.com/sYKhZaqg Has the same result. Also, the server error log isn't giving me any detail on the error 500.

Comment: I've not yet found a solution to the problem. I did however find a workaround. http://pastebin.com/ZXZxBTyg